# How do I convert from a root-EM/REM to a different size/REM, or is this not possible?

Tags: css, typography

I've been given a list of sizes to use in order to redesign a card on our website. We have a root EM of 16px, however I've been given other sizes to use in this card but the other sizes aren't based on 16px but rather another size.

Is it possible to convert the title and subtitle to 16px REM? Is the ratio the same result between different point/pixel ratios, or will they always be different?

```
Title: size 14/17px - 1.098rem?
Subtitle: size 20/21px - 1.2698rem?
Option 1: size 13.5/16px - 1.125rem
Option 2: size 13.5/16px - 1.125rem
Option 3: size 13.5/16px - 1.125rem
Subtext: size 12/16px - 1rem
Return information: size 12.8/16px - 1.0667rem
```

I used this website for conversions: https://websemantics.uk/tools/font-size-conversion-pixel-point-em-rem-percent/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So first, I determined what the ratio between each of the non-16px sizes are. So:

- 16px to 17px is 1.0625rem
- 17px to 14pt is 1.098rem
- Times them both, results in 1.166625rem
- 16px to 14pt is 1.1667rem.

And for the other one:

- 16px to 21px is 1.3125rem
- 21px to 20pt is 1.2698rem
- Times them both, results in 1.6666125rem
- 16px to 20pt is 1.6667rem

The ratios are the same. So really, given a pt all that needs to be done is replace the px with the root-EM and the ratio will work.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you could do is set the font size of the html element to 62.5%

```
html {
 font-size: 62.5%;
}
```

Which now sets 1 rem = 10px

Then set the default font size of the body

```
body {
   font-size: 1.6rem;
}
```

Now 1rem = 10px which is easier to work with for your other px values and your base font size is 16px

Comment: I can't change anything outside of the card on the website. Changing the html or body rem would affect the rest of the site which is outside my purview.

Comment: Well rem is short for root-em, so if you can't change the root em value, then your rem will remain a base of 16

Answer (score -2):

Since I am a strong opponent of rems, I can advise you to always use pixels, but if you still need Rems, use this plugin https://github.com/lore-w/2rem